# Which "Wordpress theme framework" is prefered to make custom themes without knowing much PHP

Tags: css, wordpress, xhtml, wordpress-theming

I know XHTML CSS but PHP knowledge is not much and i want to get familiar with one framework to make wordpress themes quickly for clients

[Available Frameworks](http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Frameworks)

```
* Atahualpa
* The Buffet Framework
* Carrington
* Hybrid
* Sandbox
* Thematic
* WP Framework
* Thesis
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend Thematic.

Check out [this article](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/05/27/wordpress-theme-development-frameworks/) for more information

Comment: Thematic is a nice, free alternative, but it lacks a lot in the way of theme hooks. They've got a great forum of active members who are always willing to help. If you want something a little more robust than check out Thesis.

Answer (score 1):

I have used Wp-Framework multiple times and have had no problem with it. While I know PHP fairly well, it is still just styling elements and maybe copying/pasting the php or html to re-align it in the DOM. Super easy to work with.

Answer (score 0):

I found that learning how to do a child theme using thematic to be really quite awesome.

[Here is my post](http://themeshaper.com/forums/topic/thematic-development-some-comments-on-my-first), with tips inside for those just starting out. I give an example in there that looks like this:

```
<?php
  function calltoaction() {
     include(STYLESHEETPATH . '/calltoaction.php' );
  }
  add_action('thematic_navigation_below', 'calltoaction', 1);
?>
```

And thematic has great support on the themeshaper forums.

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with [Thesis](http://diythemes.com) because you can just do a lot of stuff in the admin section and if you need to go further, is not hard to find snippets of code to paste on the custom_functions file